# Remove file path with backslash (////) from a text file

Tags: python-2.7

```
import re
b = open ('Filter_Lines.txt','w')
with open('Lines.txt') as f:
    for trim in f:
        repl = (re.sub('D:.*\\\\\\\\','',trim).rstrip('\n'))
        b.write(repl + '\n')

b.close()
```

This is my example code for remove the directory path from the text file.
This code is working fine if the directory having "\\\" slashes.But not working for "/////".

I have a text file with these below lines.

1.large -if D:/Dolby_Harmanious_kit/Dolby_Atmos_for_Sound_Bar_Products_SIDK/Test_Materials/Test_Signals/upmix_multitone/upmix_multitone_c/truehd/upmix_multitone_c_6ch_to_8ch.mlp -of out_dut.wav

2.large -if D:/Dolby_Harmanious_kit/Dolby_Atmos_for_Sound_Bar_Products_SIDK/Test_Materials/Test_Signals/upmix_multitone/upmix_multitone_l/truehd/upmix_multitone_l_6ch_to_8ch.mlp -of out_dut.wav

3.large -if D:/Dolby_Harmanious_kit/Dolby_Atmos_for_Sound_Bar_Products_SIDK/Test_Materials/Test_Signals/upmix_multitone/upmix_multitone_lfe/truehd/upmix_multitone_lfe_6ch_to_8ch.mlp -of out_dut.wav

In this i need to remove the path

"D:/Dolby_Harmanious_kit/Dolby_Atmos_for_Sound_Bar_Products_SIDK/Test_Materials/Test_Signals/upmix_multitone/upmix_multitone_c/truehd/" like different path lines i have. Can you please guide me for this.

Comment: Why do you mix path delimiters, i.e. `/` with `\\ `? If what you're doing has to be OS independent try looking at `os`. You can see what the current OS is using by using `os.path.sep`. As far as the regex is concerned, you have `D:.*\\\\\\\\\ ` , the `//` slashes don't appear there so regex will ignore them, I think.

Comment: Can you please share  the example code.

Comment: Some example inputs and outputs would be valuable. Remember to format with code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
b = open ('Filter_Lines.txt','w')
with open('Lines.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        repl = (re.sub('(D:.*\\\\)|(D:.*/)','',line).rstrip('\n'))
        b.write(repl + '\n')

b.close()
```

As far as i understand you need windwos and linux path, maybe your drive letter would change, so you can parametrize it :

```
b = open ('Filter_Lines.txt','w')
DRIVE = "E:" #windows

with open('filetest') as f:
    for trim in f:
        repl = (re.sub('(' + DRIVE +'.*\\\\)|('+ DRIVE + '.*/)','',trim).rstrip('\n'))
        b.write(repl + '\n')

b.close()
```

**EDIT** os.sep  version

```
import os
import re
b = open ('Filter_Lines.txt','w')
DRIVE = "E:" #windows
SEP = os.path.sep

if (SEP=="\\"): 
    SEP="\\\\"


with open('filetest') as f:
    for line in f:
        repl = (re.sub( DRIVE +'.*'+SEP,'',line))
        b.write(repl)

b.close()
```

Comment: trim is a pretty bad varibale name because it could be a keyword in some languages

Comment: As said in comment above you can use os.path.sep in the regex too.